# Loading css and javascript in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating Web app in codeigniter.

When I link css and javascript file in my VIEW and runs on server it gives plain text.

My css style can't apply on the page. Even with the javascript file also.

Is there any configuration required !!!

Comment: how are you `linking` the css and javascript !!!

Comment: Please post some code ....

Comment: <LINK src="../../style.css">

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned in your comment that you are calling css like  but codeigniter doesn't take full path like that. you need to use base_url() for getting external css and JavaScript files.use below example for  call css and js files

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>folder/style.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>folder/abc.js"></script>
```

Comment: And how and where to set base_url () values. And where can I store my css and javascript files

Comment: in application/config/config.php file $config['base_url']